# to write a shell script to grep IP and show to whom it belongs to?

Tags: bash, shell

To write a shell script program to grep IP (from the list given) and search the network for the IP whom it belongs to. Then if the IP belongs to vodafone, telstra, airtel, write them in a file separately for each operator.

So i wrote the script should be like :

```
for ip_address in `cat ip_address_list`;  
do  
whois $ip_address | grep 'descr' >> final_result 
done
```

the output looks like :

$] whois 62.87.90.54 | grep descr
descr:          GLOBAL MOBILE OPERATOR
descr:        AIRTEL-NETWORK
descr:          VODAFONE-NETWORK

Can we modify it more ? Can we include IF statement to separate vodafone etc to include them in a file ?

Or pls mention a good script than mine ?

Pls advise !

Comment: please edit your question to show us what the data looks like in your 'final_result' file.  Is it just an IP address and a name (vodafone, ...)? Good luck.

Comment: Also we don't know how will the name be displayed in descr ? just that we onlt know that there are only three ISPs involved vodafone, telstra, airtel.

Comment: **Just a note**: doing large scale `whois` is typically not allowed by the whois servers, and you may end up getting black-listed (blocked) if you do this for a very large amount of IP addresses...  for larger scale processing, you may consider using a IP-geo-location data set (example: http://www.maxmind.com/app/organization ) -- they typically also provide the carrier information in addition to the geolocation, and the data would reside on your machine and hence not require a `whois` lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ip_address in $(cat ip_address_list); do  
    whois $ip_address | grep 'descr' \
    | while read line ; do
      case "${line}" in 
         *GLOBAL\ MOBILE\ OPERATOR* )
            printf "${line}\n" >> gmo
          ;;
         *AIRTEL-NETWORK* )
            printf "${line}\n" >> air
          ;;
         *VODAFONE-NETWORK* )
            printf "${line}\n" >> voda
          ;;
         * )
            printf "${line}\n" >> all_others 
          ;;
        esac
      done
done
```

Note that in the case statement, you need to escape any spaces in match targets, i.e. `*GLOBAL\ MOBILE\ OPERATOR*`.

Also, I don't have a way to test this right now, so hopefully there are not too many syntax errors :-). If you do find problems, let's try and setup a chat.

And, if you are sure whois produces only one line of output per request, you probably dont't need the `while` loop. `whois $ip | read line ; case "${line}" ....` might work.

Actually managing the constantly increasing files, `air, voda, gmo` may require some thought on your part.

I hope this helps.